# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I get this error when debugging my highcharts javascript code via Firebug. Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
var valpair = [parseInt(items[0]),cumulative];
rain_series.data.push(JSON.parse(valpair));
```

`items[0]` is just `"1234567"`, and if I add `console.log(valpair)` to my code, I get this output: `[1234567, 0]` which seems to be valid JSON. Nevertheless, I'm stuck on my error (I searched for a solution, but didn't find one for my case).
Anyone here who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _"which seems to be valid JSON"_. That's an array, a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's because you're using `JSON.parse` to try to parse an array, which is not going to work.  Just get rid of the `JSON.parse`, and this should work as expected.

When you call `JSON.parse` on something that's not a string, it's going to coerce it to a string by calling `.toString()` on it.  If `valpair = [1234567, 0]`, then `valpair.toString()` is going to yield `123457,0` (this is probably dependent on the JS engine: I get `123457,0` in Chrome).  This is invalid JSON: the "unexpected non-whitespace character" is the comma.

Comment: Johabu, if that worked for you, could you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there was a time limit!  Sorry to nag!