# Unexpected non white space Error While Parsing String to JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

My String is

```
"\"{'Body': '<p>I have a issue : When I add a content that includes text and hyperlink, after that I use the wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine to set length of each lines. But in the special case, the end of line is in scope of hyperlink, so the hyperlink structure is broken. \\r\\r\\nHere is my code :</p>\\r\\r\\n\\r\\r\\n<pre><code>String languages=\"\" Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom), Bahasa Indonesia, Italiano &lt;a href=\\\\\"\"\\\\\"\"&gt;  edit&lt;/a&gt;\"\";\\r\\r\\n</code></pre>\\r\\r\\n\\r\\r\\n<p>after call wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine: </p>\\r\\r\\n\\r\\r\\n<pre><code>&lt;html&gt;Deutsch, English (All), English (United Kingdom),&lt;/br&gt; Bahasa Indonesia, Italiano &lt;a href&lt;br&gt;=\\\\\"\"\\\\\"\"&gt;  edit&lt;/a&gt;\"\";\\r\\r\\n</code></pre>\\r\\r\\n\\r\\r\\n<p>The <code>&lt;br&gt; tag</code> exists in the scope of hyperlink. How to fix this issue? Please give me advise. Thanks</p>\\r\\r\\n', 'Title': 'Use the wrapLongStringIntoMultiLine on the Jeditor pane'}\"\r"
```

I have validated the string with JSON LINt which shows it as valid JSON.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character afterJSON data at line 1 column 338 of the JSON data
```

This is the error I'm getting when i use $.parseJSON(str)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515583/json-parse-unexpected-non-whitespace-character-after-json-data-in-javascript)

Comment: It's probably best you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ entry and link it so people can work w/it and give you a solution.

Comment: Try replacing your \" with &#146 in your JSON string.  That is what JQuery is choking on.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation,I found that,there is " : " in your string so **json** is not able to understand that particular thing,lets say in your string,

```
I have a issue : When I add a content...
```

so i would like to suggest you to try " - " instead of " : "

for eg,

```
I have a issue - When I add a content...
```